# Java LinkedList - ListIterator cannot add values

Tags: java, list, sorting, linked-list, iterator

I have two fields in my custom class `List`:

- `LinkedList<String> breadList`;
- `Iterator<String> iterator`.

And I've defined two methods:

- `showBreadList()` - for displaying the contents of the list;
- `addInOrder()` - for inserting a new element into the list (the list should be updated in such a way so that elements are maintained in sorted order).

*My code:*

```
public class List {

    class LinkedListExample {
        private LinkedList<String> breadList = new LinkedList<>(); // <-- Edit from the answer: public to private
        Iterator<String> iterator;
        
        public void showBreadList() {
            iterator = breadList.iterator();
            System.out.println("Values in breadList: ");
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
        }
        
        public void addInOrder(String bread) {
            ListIterator<String> stringListIterator = breadList.listIterator();
        
            while(stringListIterator.hasNext()) {
                if(stringListIterator.next().compareTo(bread) == 0) {
                } else if(stringListIterator.next().compareTo(bread) > 0) {
                    stringListIterator.previous();
                    stringListIterator.add(bread);
                } else if(stringListIterator.next().compareTo(bread) < 0) {
                }
            }
            stringListIterator.add(bread); // <-- Edit: added
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = new List();
        
        List.LinkedListExample lle = list.new LinkedListExample();
        
        lle.addInOrder("Ciabatta");
        lle.addInOrder("Wheat Bread");
        lle.addInOrder("White Bread");
        lle.addInOrder("Sourdough");
        lle.addInOrder("Flatbread");
        lle.showBreadList();
        
    }
}
```

The list gets populated in the `main()` method via `addInOrder()`.

*Expected output:*

```
Values in breadList:  
Ciabatta  
Flatbread  
Sourdough  
Wheat Bread  
White Bread
```

*Actual output:*

```
Value in breadList:
```

I.e. I'm getting nothing. Can anybody give a hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the goal of your assignment is to learn how to deal with a `ListIterator`.

The core thing to understand about the `Iterator`s that their cursor always occupies a position in **between the elements** of the list (*and it might also be positioned before the first element and right after the last element*). And that's the position where a new element gets inserted when you invoke `ListIterator.add()`.

Here's a quote from the [official tutorial Provided by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html#Iterator):

> Intuitively speaking, the cursor is always **between two elements** — the
> one that would be returned by a call to `previous` and the one that
> would be returned by a call to next. The `n+1` valid index values
> correspond to the `n+1` gaps between elements, from the gap before the
> first element to the gap after the last one. The following figure
> shows the five possible cursor positions in a list containing four
> elements.
>
> [image]

In the method `addInOrder()` you've messed around with conditions. If fact, only one condition that would check if the `next` is lexicographically greater than the given string would be enough. If the `next` is greater we continue iteration, if not we need to move the iterator the previous position by calling `previous()` and then break from the loop.

Method `add()` will be invoked on the iterator after the loop, when iterator is the right position to insert a new element.

That's how you can fix your method:

```
public void addInOrder(String bread) {
    ListIterator<String> iterator = breadList.listIterator();
    
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String next = iterator.next();
        if (next.compareTo(bread) > 0) { // if the next element is lexicographically greater than `bread`, `bread` has to be inserted before it
            iterator.previous();         // moving to the position where the new `bread` should be inserted
            break;                       // breaking out from the loop
        }
    }
    iterator.add(bread);                 // inserting the new kind of bread
}
```

*Example with the sample data from the question:*

```
LinkedListExample lle = new LinkedListExample();
    
lle.addInOrder("Ciabatta");
lle.addInOrder("Wheat Bread");
lle.addInOrder("White Bread");
lle.addInOrder("Sourdough");
lle.addInOrder("Flatbread");
lle.showBreadList();
```

*Output:*

```
Ciabatta
Flatbread
Sourdough
Wheat Bread
White Bread
```

Comment: I'm learning Java on my own through online courses, it wasn't an assignment but does look like one. Yes, I wanted to figure out how LinkedList & iterator works! That I didn't put `break` in the loop was also an issue too, I think. It helped me a lot. Thank you!